# Search recent tags on Instagram not returning a reference timestamp

Tags: php, api, instagram

I need to retrieve all the Instagram media with a specific tag since a specific date.

Using the following call, I'm supposed to do that. So I can just keep paging it until I find an item with a timestamp before my limit date, so I stop it.

```
/tags/<tag-name>/media/recent
```

The problem is that it doesn't return any field that identifies when it was tagged. The two only timestamps that are returned from the call are:

- *create_time*: Date when the item was created
- *caption->create_time*: Date when the caption of the item was created

But they doesn't really matter since the tag can be also included via comments (which doesn't come in the response).

I believe Instagram must return the tag timestamp, since this is what this call is based on. But as it doesn't, is there any other way?

---

**Here is an example to help understanding the case:**

I wan't to bring all media tagged with #stackoverflow since 01/01/2017. For that I will call the API, retrieving page by page and checking item by item until I find one with a date before 01/01/2017

```
/tags/stackoverflow/media/recent
```

But it happens that someone can go to a really old photo and comment on it, including the tag #stackoverflow. This will make the media item go straight to the top of the API response, but there is no way to know if the tag was added before my limit date.
All dates in this commented item are before my limit date, but the tagging is recent.